# Nested scrolling Column and LazyList

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I need the whole column as one scroll component. I can't use `item` directly since I need to use [aclassen/ComposeReorderable](https://github.com/aclassen/ComposeReorderable) library for drag and drop scrolling. Any ideas?

```kotlin
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)
    ) {

        LazyColumn(){
            repeat(20) {
                item {
                    Text(text = "Item: " + it)
                }
            }
        }

        Text(text = "Header")

        LazyColumn(){
            repeat(20) {
                item {
                    Text(text = "Item: " + it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried this but the scrolling feels unnatural and I don't know how to add the `nestedScroll` on non list Composables like the header

```
  val offset = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                offset.value = (offset.value +  available.y).coerceIn(-200f, 0f)
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }
    
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.offset(y = offset.value.dp)
    ) {

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
        ){
            repeat(20) {
                item { Text(text = "Item: $it") }
            }
        }

        Text(text = "Header")

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
        ){
            repeat(20) {
                item { Text(text = "Item: $it") }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is something `ComposeReorderable` maintainers should support, create an issue there to let them know you need this feature

Comment: I think we will have to wait a bit, it's on the `Compose` roadmap https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/compose-roadmap